# MongoDb: Sort and store in a new collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection patient where documents are not sorted. I can sort it using -

db.patient.find().sort({patient_id:1,admit_date:-1})

But I want to store the sorted documents in a new collection called patient2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`$out`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator of the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to output the results to a new collection:

```js
db.patient.aggregate([
    {$sort:{patient_id:1,admit_date:-1}},
    {$out:"patient2"}
])
```

Comment: @user3858258, that's great.  Please feel free to accept/upvote the answer.  It's a nice way to encourage the community.

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense. MongoDB doesn't store the documents in any particular guaranteed order on disk. They will probably get written out in order from that aggregation, but subsequent inserts or updates will wreck the sorted order. You should use a sort with an appropriate index to return the documents in sorted order as needed.

Comment: @wdberkeley, I agree with you.  I'm not sure what the OP intends to do with the collection.  I just assumed he wants to temporarily store the results of a query and hence wanted to make him aware of the `$out` operator.